# Is it possible to get all data from table and insert to another using single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get all data from table and insert to another using single query?

Provided that two tables are the same structure

Comment: Yes.  The command is called `insert`.

Comment: Do you mean subquery insert? First select the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO t(col1, col2, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM t2
```